# How to throw customised exception rather than 500 with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, error-handling, http-status-codes

I am trying to throw a customized exception (ie. 400 with some error message ) from spring boot controller, somehow it always throws 500 instead

```
{
  "timestamp": "2021-01-06T17:39:49.648+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "invalid xxx",
  "path": "/abc/def"
}
```

I have created an exception handler to handle my customized exception thrown from my service called by the controller which suppose to return 400. When I debug it, I can see it actually has been called, but it didn't get thrown directly as the response, and if I carry on debug, I can see the BasicErrorController will still be called (which I thought it shouldn't as I have a customized exception handler, please correct me I am wrong), and I can see the status for response has been changed to 500 at this point and my customized exception has been wrapped by this "internal server error"

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class RegistrationExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = RegistrationException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleRegistrationError(RegistrationException ex){
        return  ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(ex);
    }
```

I have configured my application class to scan this handler class and I think it is working, as it will be called when RegistrationException is thrown by the service.

In my service, I call this and cascade the exception to the controller
throw new RegistrationException("invalid xxx");

Not sure where I have done wrong. I would expect to see 400 as below. Please advise. thanks

```
{
  "timestamp": "2021-01-06T17:39:49.648+0000",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "invalid xxx",
  "path": "/abc/def"
}
```

Comment: sorry what is your question ? looks like it is working right ?

Comment: I was expecting return 400 rather 500

Answer (score 0):

The `@ExceptionHandler` works only WITHIN the `@Controller` class it's in.

Comment: what should i do if the exception is thrwon in a @Component

Comment: idk, wrap it in a `try - catch`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `@ControllerAdvice` to handle them globally as `@ExceptionHandler` is controller based (*cf: Spring blog linked below at **Controller Based Exception Handling***)

```java
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)  // 400
    @ExceptionHandler(RegistrationException.class)
    public void handleConflict() {
        // Nothing to do
    }
}
```

Using [Spring Blog](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) at **Global Exception Handling**